# Setting a Var After X Time?

Tags: javascript

Slowly working on a new project for my twitch channel right.. and I'm getting stuck, perhaps there's not a way to do this but I thought there was...

Let's say I have a javascript with a options variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    channel: "Chanel Name",
};
var player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options);
player.setVolume(0.00);
</script>
```

Now, after 2-3 minutes on being on the page, I want to change "player.setVolume" to value 0.5 (auto unmute) How would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Using a timeout. `setTimeout(callback, timeout)`.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for the code to track how long a Twitch Player has been on your page? Or are you just looking for a simple timer in JavaScript? If you're looking for a timer, @Li357 is correct, a setTimeout call would do the trick, and there are a few answers below that explain that. Otherwise, someone would need to check the official Twitch API documentation.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I'll take a look at the comments shortly. It seems i may have a problem with the command player.setVolume(0.5); as well in twitch's API - so might need some more investigating as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you could do:

```
function volume() {
    player.setVolume = 0.5;
}

setTimeout(volume, 120000);
```

This sets `player.setVolume` to 0.5 after two minutes. For three minutes, it's this:

```
setTimeout(volume, 180000);
```

Answer (score 1):

After 2 Minutes :

```
               2     *     60      *      1000 = 120000 ms
         Minute^     Second^    Milisecond^
```

So :

```
setTimeout( function() { player.setVolume(0.5) }, 120000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve your goal, you'll need to use the `setTimeout` method, which executes a callback function after a desired amount of time, it accepts two arguments: the first argument is the function to be executed after the amount of time, the second argument is the amount of time, in milliseconds, you want the function to be executed after.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
     width: 400,
     height: 300,
     channel: "Chanel Name",
   },
   time = 2, /*amount of time in seconds that you want the callback to be executed after. change this variable's value per your requirements. */
   player = new Twitch.Player("<player div ID>", options);
player.setVolume(0.00);
setTimeout(function(){
  player.setVolume(0.50); // sets the volume to 0.5. Change it per your requirements.
}, time * 60 * 1000); // 2 * 60 * 1000 = 120 000 milliseconds.
</script>
```

[Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) about `setTimeout` method.

Hope I pushed you further.